# Transição de pagina - Mudar de tela após mensagem de sucesso de enviao de email - Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

sou iniciante em Flutter, preciso de ajuda com algo que embora pareça simples eu não consigo encontrar uma solução, nem mesmo um widget que me ajude com isso. Ainda que fosse um direcionamento já me ajudaria!

Eu gostaria que após uma mensagem de sucesso de envio de mensagem via SMTP para e-mail a tela mudasse automaticamente, ou até após uma quantidade de tempo, segundos, esse é meu código da pagina que quero mudar para outra após a mensagem de sucesso.

**Esta é a tela de preenchimento de dados nos inputs de mensagens:**

```
import 'package:animated_text_kit/animated_text_kit.dart';
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
import 'dart:io';
import 'PaginadeConfirmacao.dart';
import 'package:image_picker/image_picker.dart';

// é um statefull
class MensagemChat extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MensagemChatState createState() => _MensagemChatState();
}

class _MensagemChatState extends State<MensagemChat> {
  TextEditingController _textNome = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _textProblem = TextEditingController();
  TextEditingController _textEmail = TextEditingController();

  //a Funcação abaixo bloqueia o giro de tela, permitindo assim que o app fique no modo vertical
  void blockgiro() {
    SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
        [DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
  }

  //Fim da fução de giro

  // Função da CAMERA E GALERIA - GALERIA, CAMERA
  File _imagem;
  File _imagemTemporaria;

  //Funcação para pegar a imagem na galeria

  void ImagemGaleria() async {
    _imagemTemporaria =
        await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.gallery);
    setState(() {
      _imagem = _imagemTemporaria;
    });
  }

  // Função para tirar foto
  void ImagemCamera() async {
    _imagemTemporaria = await ImagePicker.pickImage(source: ImageSource.camera);
    setState(() {
      _imagem = _imagemTemporaria;
    });
  }

// Final da função de camera/galeria

  @override
  //Esse é o nosso layout para utilizarmos em nosso formulario
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
            centerTitle: true,
            title: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(width: 20.0, height: 100.0),
                Text(
                  "Ouvidoria",
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                ),
                SizedBox(width: 20.0, height: 100.0),
                RotateAnimatedTextKit(
                  isRepeatingAnimation: true,
                    duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                    onTap: () {
                      print("");
                    },
                    text: ["Móvel", "Móvel", "Móvel"],
                    textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontFamily: "Horizon"),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start),
              ],
            )),
        body: SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(16),
                child: Column(
//Abixo irá ficar nossos botões/caixa de texto para coletar os dados
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 10),

                        child: TextField(
                          controller: _textNome,
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Nome",
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                              borderSide: new BorderSide(),
                            ),
                            //fillColor: Colors.green
                          ),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          style: new TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Poppins",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(children: <Widget>
                      [ RaisedButton(child:Text("Sim") ,onPressed:(){},
                            ), Container(child: Text("Deseja envair como anonimo?"),)

                      ],),
                      //Abaixo esta o e-mail no titulo da variavel, mas não é
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 10),
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: _textEmail,
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Bairro ou rua da ocorrência",
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                              borderSide: new BorderSide(),
                            ),
                            //fillColor: Colors.green
                          ),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                          style: new TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Poppins",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                        margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 10, top: 10),
                        child: TextField(
                          controller: _textProblem,
                          maxLines: 5,
                          decoration: new InputDecoration(
                            labelText: "Ocorrencia:",
                            fillColor: Colors.white,
                            border: new OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderRadius: new BorderRadius.circular(25.0),
                              borderSide: new BorderSide(),
                            ),
                            //fillColor: Colors.green
                          ),
                          keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                          style: new TextStyle(
                            fontFamily: "Poppins",
                          ),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Container(
                          child: _imagem != null
                              ? Image.file(_imagem)
                              : Center(
                                  child: Text('Capture uma foto'),
                                )),
                      Padding(
                        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(10),
                        child: Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                          children: [
                            IconButton(
                                icon: Icon(
                                  Icons.camera_alt,
                                  color: Colors.teal,
                                  size: 35,
                                ),
                                onPressed: () {
                                  ImagemCamera();
                                }),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                      Row(
                          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                          children: <Widget>[
                            Container(
                              margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                              child: RaisedButton(
                                  color: Colors.red,
                                  splashColor: Colors.blue,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "Enviar",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontSize: 20,
                                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                  onPressed: () {
                                    Navigator.push(
                                        context,
                                        MaterialPageRoute(
                                            builder: (context) =>
                                                PaginaBoasvindas(
                                                    _textNome.text,
                                                    _textEmail.text,
                                                    _textProblem.text,
                                                    _imagem)));
                                    BoxDecoration(
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
                                      color: Colors.redAccent,
                                      boxShadow: [
                                        BoxShadow(
                                            color: Colors.red,
                                            blurRadius: 50,
                                            offset: Offset(
                                              10,
                                              0,
                                            ))
                                      ],
                                    );
                                  }),
                            ),
                          ]),
                    ]))));
  }
}
```

**E essa tela para qual esta sendo direcionado, é nesta segunda tela que gostaria que após confirmado o envio da mensagem o usuário fosse direcionado para uma tela de agradecimento.**

```
 import 'dart:io';
    
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    import 'package:mailer/mailer.dart';
    import 'package:mailer/smtp_server.dart';
    import 'package:mailer/smtp_server/gmail.dart';
    import 'package:animated_text_kit/animated_text_kit.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    
    
    // ignore: must_be_immutable
    class PaginaBoasvindas extends StatelessWidget {
      String _nome;
      String _email;
      String _problema;
      File _imagem;
    
    
    
      PaginaBoasvindas(this._nome, this._email, this._problema, this._imagem, );
    
      //a Funcação abaixo bloqueia o giro de tela, permitindo assim que o app fique no modo vertical
      void blockgiro() {
        SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
            [DeviceOrientation.portraitDown, DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);
      }
    
      //Fim da fução de giro
    
      void sendMail() async {
        String username = '*****@gmail.com';
        String password = '!@#*****@#';
    
        final smtpServer = gmail(username, password);
    
        final message = Message()
          ..from = Address(username, '$_nome')
          ..recipients.add('l******')
          ..ccRecipients.addAll(['destCc1@example.com', 'destCc2@example.com'])
          ..bccRecipients.add(Address('bccAddress@example.com'))
          ..subject = 'Ouvidoria Móvel - ${DateTime.now()}'
          ..text = 'A localização é:$_email,'
              'Problema que precisa de solução: $_problema, e a foto da ocorrência: $_imagem';
    
        try {
          final sendReport = await send(message, smtpServer);
          print('Mensagem enviada: ' + sendReport.toString());
        } on MailerException catch (e) {
          print('Mensagem não enviada.');
          for (var p in e.problems) {
            print('Problem: ${p.code}: ${p.msg}');
          }
        }
      }
    
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        blockgiro();
        return Stack(children: <Widget>[
          Image.asset(
            "Assets/image/appouvidoria_bg.png",
            fit: BoxFit.fitHeight,
            height: 1000,
          ),
          Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(
                centerTitle: true,
                title: Row(
                  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    SizedBox(width: 20.0, height: 100.0),
                    Text(
                      "Iremos",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0),
                    ),
                    SizedBox(width: 20.0, height: 100.0),
                    RotateAnimatedTextKit(
                        isRepeatingAnimation: true,
                        duration: const Duration(milliseconds: 2000),
                        onTap: () {
                          print("");
                        },
                        text: ["Mais além", "Juntos", "Venceremos"],
                        textStyle: TextStyle(fontSize: 24.0, fontFamily: "Horizon"),
                        textAlign: TextAlign.start),
                  ],
                )),
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            body: SingleChildScrollView(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                child: Container(
                    margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                    color: Colors.transparent,
                    child: Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 120, top: 20),
                          ),
                          Column(
                            children: [
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(
                                    10),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          blurRadius: 1,
                                          color: Colors.black87,
                                          offset: Offset(1, 1))
                                    ],
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
                                    color: Colors.red),
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: Text(
                                    "$_nome, verifique se sua mensagem esta correta:",
                                    style: TextStyle(
                                        fontStyle: FontStyle.normal,
                                        fontSize: 18,
                                        color: Colors.white),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container( padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                                  bottom: 50, right: 12, left: 12, top: 20),),
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          blurRadius: 1,
                                          color: Colors.black87,
                                          offset: Offset(1, 1))
                                    ],
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
                                    color: Colors.white),
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    width: 250.0,
                                    child: TypewriterAnimatedTextKit(
                                      pause: Duration(minutes: 10),
                                      speed: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        print("Tap Event");
                                      },
                                      text: ['Seu nome é: $_nome'],
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontSize: 20.0,
                                          fontFamily: "Agne"),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          blurRadius: 1,
                                          color: Colors.black87,
                                          offset: Offset(1, 1))
                                    ],
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(13),
                                    color: Colors.white),
                                child: Align(
                                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                  child: SizedBox(
                                    width: 250.0,
                                    child: TypewriterAnimatedTextKit(
                                      pause: Duration(minutes: 10),
                                      speed: Duration(milliseconds: 100),
                                      onTap: () {
                                        print("Tap Event");
                                      },
                                      text: ['A localização é essa: $_email'],
                                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.black,
                                          fontSize: 20.0,
                                          fontFamily: "Agne"),
                                      textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                      boxShadow: [
                                        BoxShadow(
                                            blurRadius: 1,
                                            color: Colors.black87,
                                            offset: Offset(1, 1))
                                      ],
                                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                      color: Colors.white),
                                  child: Align(
                                    alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                                    child: SizedBox(
                                      width: 250.0,
                                      child: TypewriterAnimatedTextKit(
                                        pause: Duration(minutes: 10),
                                        onTap: () {
                                          print("Tap Event");
                                        },
                                        text: ['Seu problema é: $_problema'],
                                        textStyle: TextStyle(
                                            color: Colors.black,
                                            fontSize: 24.0,
                                            fontFamily: "Agne"),
                                        textAlign: TextAlign.start,
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  )),
                              Container(
                                child: _imagem != null
                                    ? Image.file(
                                        _imagem,
                                        fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                                      )
                                    : Center(
                                        child: Text('Capture uma foto'),
                                      ),
                                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                                    boxShadow: [
                                      BoxShadow(
                                          blurRadius: 1,
                                          color: Colors.black87,
                                          offset: Offset(1, 1))
                                    ],
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30),
                                    color: Colors.white),
                              ),
                              Container(
                                padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20, top: 20),
                              ),
                            ],
                          ),
                          Row(
                              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.baseline,
                              mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                              children: <Widget>[
                                Container(
                                    margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20),
                                    child: MaterialButton(
                                      padding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                                      disabledColor: Colors.greenAccent[100],
                                      disabledTextColor: Colors.blue[100],
                                      elevation: 5.0,
                                      color: Colors.red,
                                      splashColor: Colors.blue,
                                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                                        borderRadius:
                                            new BorderRadius.circular(18.0),
                                        side: BorderSide(color: Colors.black),
                                      ),
                                      child: Text(
                                        "Enviar",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                            fontSize: 25,
                                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                                            color: Colors.white),
                                      ),
                                      onPressed: sendMail,
                                    ))
                              ]),
                          Container(
                            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 50),
                          )
                        ]))),
          )
        ]);
      }
    }
```

Comment: Como você está fazendo a navegação? Ta usando rotas nomeadas? E essa tela que você deseja exibir, o usuário vai poder clicar em "voltar" e cair na tela de envio de email novamente?

Comment: Estou usando um controlador de texto para pegar os dados do input e levar para a outra pagina,

Comment: Estou usando rotas nomeadas e sim, haveria botões para direcionar o usuário para a tela de envio novamente. Tentei mandar o código da tela de preenchimento dos campos de mensagem, mas não consegui.